# using webpack code splitting, how to load chunks and HTML layout?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, webpack

I use webpack to build chunks, to be loaded on demand (code splitting); each chunk is rendering React components into DOM elements (divs). I need HTML to create those divs: how and when should I load the corresponding HTML ? And how should I load the chunks on demand ?

I use jQuery's `load` function to insert HTML from files in container `divs`. In addition I put a `<script>` tag to tell which chunk should be loaded but I find it clumsy and not elegant at all compared to the rest of my application code.

Is there a less brittle way to do this?

Comment: Do you talk of server side rendered html? I think normaly the the few kilobytes of code your components will add compared to lib code are not worth splitting into chunks. Do you see a huge difference in size?

Comment: the difference can be seen in the loading time, on the client side : parts of the app are only loaded on demand. But it doesn't make a huge difference, I agree - at least in my case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that what I wanted to achieve can be done via [react-router](https://github.com/rackt/react-router), simply I didn't know ;)

```
<Route name="app" component={require('./app.jsx')}>
    <Route path="/" name="home" component={require('./homepage-container.jsx')}/>
    <Route path="/otherpath" name="other" component={require('./other.jsx')}/>
    ... add as many routes as wanted
</Route>
```

The jsx files get loaded on demand, and there is no need for plain HTML
as I am using react the design is that every part is a component.
In this example it is enough to activate a link to `#/otherpath` in order to
get the `other` component to be loaded as a child of the upper level component (route called `app`).

Answer (score 2):

You should use `require.ensure` for dynamic route loading. Even better, if you set up your project to use Webpack 2 + Tree shaking, you can use `System.import`.

Here's how:

```js
import App from 'containers/App';
function errorLoading(err) {
  console.error('Dynamic page loading failed', err);
}
function loadRoute(cb) {
  return (module) => cb(null, module.default);
}
export default {
  component: App,
  childRoutes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      getComponent(location, cb) {
        System.import('pages/Home')
          .then(loadRoute(cb))
          .catch(errorLoading);
      }
    },
    {
      path: 'blog',
      getComponent(location, cb) {
        System.import('pages/Blog')
          .then(loadRoute(cb))
          .catch(errorLoading);
      }
    }
  ]
};
```

You can get the entire guide in this blog post: [Automatic Code Splitting for React Router](https://medium.com/modus-create-front-end-development/automatic-code-splitting-for-react-router-w-es6-imports-a0abdaa491e9#.7rdseexlw)